# Resizing animated GIF loses transparency and animation

Tags: c#, .net, gif, animated-gif, imageresizer

I am using the ImageResizer .NET component on an IIS hosted .NET web-service to handle resizing images that are stored in Amazon S3.

It works great for everything except animated GIFs (so no problem with JPEG, PNG, standard GIF)

With an animated GIF however the animation is lost and the transparency switches to black.

Doesn't seem to make any difference whether I add an explicit *format=gif* parameter to the query string.

The output from the resizer.debug page are shown below:

```
Image resizer diagnostic sheet      12/08/2014 09:36:08

2 Issues detected:

(Warning):  To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.


(Warning):  NoCache is only for development usage, and cannot scale to production use.
            Add DiskCache or CloudFront for production use


You are using plugins from the Performance Edition: S3Reader2 (Performance Edition), AnimatedGifs (Performance Edition), PrettyGifs (Performance Edition)

Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader2.S3Reader2
ImageResizer.Plugins.AnimatedGifs.AnimatedGifs
ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs.PrettyGifs
ImageResizer.Plugins.Logging.LoggingPlugin

Configuration:

<resizer>
<plugins>
<add name="S3Reader2" vpp="false" buckets="implat.imagr.220triathlon,implat.imagr.babyexpert,implat.imagr.control,implat.imagr.gardenersworld,implat.imagr.golfmagic,implat.imagr.junior,implat.imagr.loveyourhair,implat.imagr.madeformums,implat.imagr.outdoormagic,implat.imagr.outdoorsmagic,implat.imagr.radiotimes,implat.imagr.runnersworld,implat.imagr.test,implat.imagr.visordown,implat.imagr.youandyourwedding" accessKeyId="[redacted]" secretAccessKey="[redacted]" prefix="~/s3/" useSubdomains="true" region="eu-west-1" />
<add name="AnimatedGifs" />
<add name="PrettyGifs" />
<add name="Logging" />
</plugins>
<diagnostics enableFor="Localhost" />
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, colors, dither, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, scale, stretch, crop, cropxunits, cropyunits, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, ignoreicc, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, anchor, dpi, mode, zoom, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi, 

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/8.0 on Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 and CLR 4.0.30319.18444
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: x86 !! Warning, running as 32-bit on a 64-bit OS(AMD64). This will limit ram usage !!
Executing assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
IntegratedPipeline: True

Loaded assemblies:

mscorlib                                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18444 Info: 4.0.30319.18444
System.Web                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18446 Info: 4.0.30319.18446
System                                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.Core                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.Web.ApplicationServices           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18446 Info: 4.0.30319.18446
System.Configuration                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.Xml                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.Runtime.Caching                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
Microsoft.JScript                        Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 11.0.50938.18408 Info: 11.0.50938.18408
Microsoft.CSharp                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.Data                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.Web.Services                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.Drawing                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.EnterpriseServices                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.IdentityModel                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.Runtime.Serialization             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.ServiceModel                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.ServiceModel.Activation           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.ServiceModel.Web                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.Activities                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.ServiceModel.Activities           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.WorkflowServices                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.Web.Extensions                    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.Data.DataSetExtensions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.Xml.Linq                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.Web.DynamicData                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
AWSSDK                                   Assembly: 2.2.2.0         File: 2.2.2.0        
ImageResizer                             Assembly: 3.4.3.103       File: 3.4.3.103       Info: 3-4-3  Commit: bf92fd7
ImageResizer.Plugins.AnimatedGifs        Assembly: 3.4.3.103       File: 3.4.3.103       Info: 3-4-3  Commit: bf92fd7
ImageResizer.Plugins.Logging             Assembly: 3.4.3.103       File: 3.4.3.103       Info: 3-4-3  Commit: bf92fd7
ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs          Assembly: 3.4.3.103       File: 3.4.3.103       Info: 3-4-3  Commit: bf92fd7
ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader2           Assembly: 3.4.3.103       File: 3.4.3.103       Info: 3-4-3  Commit: bf92fd7
Imagr.Resizer                            Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
NLog                                     Assembly: 3.1.0.0        
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.20710.0    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 12.3.50717.0   
System.Xaml                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime Assembly: 12.3.0.0        File: 12.3.50717.0   
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure             Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Tracing Assembly: 12.3.0.0        File: 12.3.50717.0   
System.Web.RegularExpressions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.Data.Services.Design              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
App_global.asax.2z_wgdg2                 Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
System.Net.Http                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.Net.Http.WebRequest               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
System.ServiceModel.Internals            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
SMDiagnostics                            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.18408 Info: 4.0.30319.18408
```

Thanks in advance!

Adrian

Comment: What do your request querystrings look like? Have you cleared your browser cache after adding the AnimatedGifs and PrettyGif plugins?

Comment: Without more information (exact command strings and source .gif used), I don't think this question can be answered.