# Compress GIF image without loosing animation

Tags: c#, .net

I am compressing images by reducing height and width to reduce their size and it works fine for images that don't have animation but if I do this for animated images, it will reduce the size but loose animation as well. I haven't tried anything till yet as I couldn't find any solution online. Any Idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381989/compress-animated-gif-image-size-using-c-sharp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763630/c-sharp-gif-image-to-memorystream-and-back-lose-animation

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261428/resizing-animated-gif-loses-transparency-and-animation

Comment: @SachithMW thanks for reply but in first link OP is making GIF out of multiple images, in second one, OP is trying to read GIF from `PictureBox` without loosing animation. I need to compress it without any loss of animation.

Comment: You must first find a library that can encode an animated GIF, .NET does not have one.  Which is why "it doesn't work".  But otherwise a good way to compress a GIF :)  The file format already uses LZW compression, good luck making that better.

Comment: fyi. when people say "compression" they usually mean limiting the dynamic range of an image - the range in available shades/color that individual pixels are allowed to have. (should the color of a single pixel be represented by 8bit integer, or 10bit or..). They usually dont mean image size.